# AWS Lightsail domain unreachable

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, nameserver, amazon-lightsail

I created a NodeJS instance, set the nameservers in the domain host, and added a few records for www and other subdomains.

I can only access the instance via public IP, and subdomains, but the main domain is not reachable ("server DNS address could not be found").

These are the domains and subdomains:

Main: jazzpiano.tv (unreachable)
en.jazzpiano.tv
www.jazzpiano.tv

I'm still waiting for the 72 hours period to pass in order to see what happens, still I find odd that subdomains ARE currently reachable but not the root domain.

Any help will be mostly appreciated.

Is this normal? Is there anything else I can do except waiting (and praying to God) after 72 hs. my domain will work?

Thanks

Comment: Using Google DNS (`8.8.8.8 `), I got all three `A` records correctly.
Maybe there is a negative response cached somewhere in your DNS setup?

Comment: Yes! I've just set my network to use Google DNS and looks fine :) There was also a problem with the A record for the main domain, AWS didn't allowed me to set it, but then I realised it was misunderstanding about the Lightsail UI, I'm posting a full response now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was a combination of a lack of understanding of the AWS Lightsail UI combined with the DNS cache.

There are two text input fields to set sub-domain and IP, which on edit Lightsail populates with examples. The default is to set a sub-domain, but is never explicit about how to set a simple A record for the basic domain.

This led to a series of assumptions on my part that were entirely mistaken, and I spent quite a lot of time setting, unsetting, waiting a few hours, and trying again, instead of simply filling the sub-domain field with jazzpiano.tv, which I did at the end but could only see after a few hours trying with Google DNS, as suggested by Pablo.

Hope this helps to others newbies like me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,confusing bit is that lightsail entry form offers you to enter subdomain, placing extra dot in front of your main domain. You need to delete the dot and it will allow you to save!